# how to call php website through API using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i am trying to call a php Api through API using asp.net c#, could anyone please help me
i want to call the following API
username: admin
password: ****

```
http://Ip Hidden/WHMCS_1/includes/api.php
```

[image]
check the following code it throw error 
thanks in advance

Comment: is it a restful API and what content-type does it support?

Comment: You would at least need to provide more information about the remote API in question: if it's SOAP, then the WSDL would help. Or maybe it's REST, or maybe it's a custom protocol, etc.

Comment: i have add some code kindly check why its throw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question so this answer is broad too.

You can use the `WebClient` class for this:

> Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a
>   resource identified by a URI

**[WebClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.90).aspx)** - MSDN docs with example usage

In later versions of .net you can use:

**[HttpClient class](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)** - MSDN docs with example usage

Comment: i have mention code above but its throw an error , i don't know whats the problem is ?

Comment: @RazimKhan A 403 error is the server denying access. Do you have any documentation for the API? If so you really need to check what a valid http request looks like, check that your sent request matches via a tool like fiddler. Also double check credentials & hashing process is as expected. Failing that contact API vendor.